# Keycloak execute-actions-email admin API is not working

Tags: java, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to send update password link to an user email which is created in Keycloak, I'm trying to use **PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email** API, but its not sending the email.
[image: Keycloak API Call Screenshot]

Its returning 204 response but not sending any to that user. I have configured the Email smtp setting properly in Keycloak realm settings and I tested that its working. and the user email Id also valid one. But its not sending the Email.

Below is my Email Setting in Keycloak

[image: Email settings Screenshot]

I received email when I click on the **Test connection**

Comment: enable ssl should be checked